# Invoke JavaScript callback from a Java method asynchronously using Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, asynchronous, closures, rhino

Suppose I have a script like so:

```
function hello() {
  var x = 42; // notice the closure over x in the success handler
  stuffExecutor.execute({
    success: function (result) { println("Success: " + (result + x)); },
    failure: function (reason) { println("Failure: " + reason; }
  });
  println("Starting to execute stuff...");
}
```

Let's assume `stuffExecutor` is some Java object which has an `execute()` method with the appropriate signature that I've put into the context.

I can imagine implementing the `execute()` method to defer its action until after the `hello()` script returns (thereby printing "Starting to execute stuff..." first before either succeeding or failing), but from there I don't know how to go back and invoke the handlers later, after the deferred execution completes. In particular, the `success` handler closes over the local variable `x` from the `hello()` function, so I'd somehow need to "get back" the old context (or otherwise store it for later use).

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of approaches you could take, but here is the one I'd recommend for maximum cleanliness and clarity of the code on each side.

I'm assuming `success` and `failure` are strings, but the transformation is straightforward if they are something else.

On the Java side, make your API:

```java
public class StuffExecutor {
  public abstract static class Listener {
    public abstract void success(String result);
    public abstract void failure(String reason);
  }

  private void stuff(Listener listener) {
    try {
      String result = doIt();
      listener.success(result);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      listener.failure(t.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public void execute(final Listener listener) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        stuff(listener);
      }
    }).start();
  }
}
```

Now on the JavaScript side:

```javascript
function hello() {
  var x = 42; // notice the closure over x in the success handler
  stuffExecutor.execute(new JavaAdapter(Packages.my.package.StuffExecutor.Listener, {
    success: function (result) { println("Success: " + (result + x)); },
    failure: function (reason) { println("Failure: " + reason; }
  }));
  println("Starting to execute stuff...");
}
```

Like I said, other approaches could work. You could pass functions directly to your Java API (they will appear as `org.mozilla.javascript.Callable`) but then your Java syntax for invoking them gets a lot more complex and messy.

Note that there was a bug in JavaAdapter in the 1.7R4 release (which has caused many people to clamor for a 1.7R5 that has not come). This should work with any other release of Rhino or with the current master on GitHub.

Note that `result` and `reason` would be `java.lang.String` objects in this scenario, not native JavaScript strings. In your code it would make no difference but if you needed to use them later as JavaScript strings you'd probably want to convert them using `String(result)` and `String(failure)`.

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for, as it lacks the "asynchronous" component. In this solution, the calling thread (and thus the Rhino excecution) will block until `execute()` calls one of the handlers and returns, regardless of how `execute()` actually does its work. In my particular case, I need the calling thread to be released, and then resumed later, potentially on another thread. I've been looking at Rhino's support for continuations, and that seems to provide what I'm looking for.

Comment: Let me actually revise my question a little. With continuations, I think I'll be going for a different approach in my API. It'll look like a normal value-returning function instead of a function that takes success/failure callbacks as arguments. The callback style is still doable with continuations, but it's needlessly more complex.

Comment: I changed my mind about reworking the question, since it then makes your answer totally irrelevant. I've left it in its original form, but I'm still looking for the asynchronous answer. I'll probably work it out some time this week and post my results, if nobody else gets around to it.

Comment: Sorry, that was intended to cover the asynchronous case, in the section with these code comments: "Implementation omitted; use whatever multithreading strategy you want to use" and "Invoke the success / failure methods of listener with appropriate arguments depending what happens." I've filled this in a bit to make it clearer. I think it meets your needs.

Comment: Not bad, I'll accept it for the purposes of this question.

That said, the reason I'm still leaning toward continuations is that the js code above requires direct invocation of Java classes, which won't be acceptable in my scenario. Continuations enable a non-blocking return-value semantic instead of a non-blocking callback-based semantic, letting the js user write "normal" code without using Java classes directly.

Comment: I haven't looked at the continuations stuff much but it sounds like you have. An alternative to continuations would be to alter my example to have `StuffExecutor.execute(Scriptable)` instead of `Listener` and then build the Listener instance on the Java side. But the Java code would be cast-filled ugliness in that scenario.

Comment: Actually, that's not a bad suggestion. Would you mind amending your answer accordingly? I wouldn't mind seeing what that looks like...